# Only last button is created through JSON response

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]    {
"title":"Do you already have art work?",
"type":"buttons",
"unique":"_09xslnys6",
"preselect_value":"",
"conditional_option":"",
"conditional_value":"",
"required":"on",
"values":[
{
"key":"Yes",
"price":""
},
{
"key":"No",
"price":""
}
]
},

This is my JSON response.I am creating buttons for the values "YES" , "NO".The code I am using is this as shown below.

```
View option_spinner_layout = View.inflate(ProductView.this,R.layout.option_spinner_layout,null);
     TextView opt_text = option_spinner_layout.findViewById(R.id.opt_text_name);
     if (optionData.has("required") && optionData.getString("required").equals("1"))
     opt_text.setText(optionData.getString("title") + "*");
     else
     opt_text.setText(optionData.getString("title"));
     Button but = option_spinner_layout.findViewById(R.id.but);
     LinearLayout layout = option_spinner_layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
     JSONArray jsonArray =optionData.getJSONArray("values");
     for (int j = 0;j<jsonArray.length();j++)
     {
     JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
     if(jsonObject.has("key"))
     {
     String value = jsonObject.getString("key");
     but.setText(value);
     if(but.getParent() != null) {
     ((ViewGroup)but.getParent()).removeView(but); // <- fix
     }
     layout.addView(but);
     }
     }
     options_additional.addView(option_spinner_layout);
```

But using above code when I run my app only The last value of JSON response is created as button (i.e. "NO" in this case.)"YES" button is not created.Kindly help me on this for creating two buttons (YES and NO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're just assigning the one button you have with the value yes and no. You're not creating a new button so, the each text is set to your button, but sine there is just one the last value always overwrites the button. Here you want to create a new button.

Inside your loop add

```
if(jsonObject.has("key"))
     {
     String value = jsonObject.getString("key"); 
     // set as your needs
     LayoutParams params = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     Button button = new Button(this);
     button.setText(value);
     button.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(button);
  }
```